# Как выводить сообщения, если программа добавляется в авто запуск?

Tags: delphi-7, dll

Задача состоит в следующем: 
если запустить программу и она добавляется в авто запуск, то вывести сообщение (ну например `ShowMessage`).

Принцип как `AntiWinLocker`.

Answer (score 1):

уточните, вы хотите свою программу в автозапуск поместить или хотите контролировать что программа в автозапуск прописалась?

в любом случае 2 вещи проверяете:
1 папка автозапуск
2 реестр

Comment: Нет,проверка записи программ в автозапуск.
Ну например какой-то вирус захотел в авторан пройти,а программа проверяет  выводит сообщение 'Так-то так какой-то вирусяк в авторан идет.'
Ну или так программа следит за автораном,если кто-то туда записуется тогда они пишит ShowMessage .

Comment: все верно, создаешь сервис, в сервисе таймер с интервалом например в 1 секунду, получаешь список того что есть в автозапуске, сверяешь со старым списком, если что то добавилось выводишь сообщение.

будет не лень напишу код и добавлю в ответ.

Comment: Буду пробовать:D

Comment: плохая идея, почитайте как работает processmonitor

Comment: Пробуй что не будет получатся спрашивай подскажем :)